# ORA-01109: Database not open - I can't create a user account

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've recently installed Oracle 11g on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

I can't create a user; the following is the error I got

```
SQL> create user rachid identified by rachid;
create user rachid identified by rachid
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01109: database not open
```

The instance is started :

```
SQL> select status from v$instance;

STATUS
------------------------------------
STARTED
```

Do you have any solution to overcome this issue ?

Comment: [`alter database open`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/start.htm#ADMIN11153)? Is it mounted but not open for a reason though? Did the installation or database creation report errors which left the DB in that state?

Comment: No it's not mounted ,

Comment: SQL> alter database open
  2  ;
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01507: database not mounted

Comment: So you must have done `startup nomount`, and you need to `alter database mount` before `... open`. Or shut down and start up again. But that might be even more of an indication that something is actually wrong. Did you check the DB creation log, or the alert log? Do you get errors from mounting or shutting down/restarting the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to open it using

```
ALTER DATABASE OPEN
```

or you can try to shut it and start again and then try to create the user:

```
$ sqlplus sys/Change12345@orc01 as sysdba

SQL> shut immediate 
SQL> startup
```

Comment: Its already opened but still getting the same error while making connection in Oracle SQL Developer software. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706962/oracle-db-service-is-already-opened-but-still-getting-database-not-open-error